# iMessages change text color

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app is showing iMessages ViewController via UIActivityController. However, the colors of labels are all messed up (blue so they are barely visible). I think this is because the view controller is using my app's tint color. See below.

[image]

How can i fix this?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into something similar with presenting `MFMailComposerViewController` modally. Try setting the appearance of your app's tint color to `nil` when presenting the activity controller, and then back to your desired app tint when it completes. Here's what I did with `MFMailComposer`. You should be able to modify for your activity controller:

```
...
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:nil];  // Set to default before presenting
MFMailComposeViewController *mailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
...

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:MyAppsCustomColor];  // set it back when finished
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**EDIT**
When I use this solution, it changes the nav bar appearance in the presented modal that is selected in the activity view controller (messages, mail, etc). I'm setting my app's nav bar appearance to blue in my delegate, and then back to blue in the completion block. The app's nav bar remains blue, and the presented messages/mail modal is shown with the default light gray nav bar.

```
UIActivityViewController* avc =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@""]
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
avc.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    // ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Set tint color back to blue.
        // This block is executed whether the user finishes or cancels.
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [[self navigationController] setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    });
};
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:nil];
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I am presenting it using UIActivityViewController so I don't have access to these delegate methods. What you are suggesting should work but unfortunately I don't have access to these methods as I am not directly presenting the Mail view controller. They are being presented by the UIActivityController

Comment: This link has some general info about activity views and how to handle different actions: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch26.html#_activity_view

Comment: I've been to that link, it does not contain anything relevant to my question.

Comment: Seriously? "You set the controller’s `completionHandler` to a block that will be called when the user’s interaction with the activity interface ends." AKA use a completion block like they demo to execute code when the user finishes with their activity controller. Or, if they cancel: "If you set a delegate for the `UIPopoverController`, it will be sent `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` if the user cancels"

Comment: Yes. Seriously. The block is only called if the presented view controller is shown and then it ends. Not when it's shown. So for example if I was to set my tint color to nil, there's no way for me to know if the presented view controller was never shown (i.e. the user cancelled out of the UIActivityController). Think about it.

Comment: @0xSina Check the edits- I tested with the specific situation and it only changes the color of the nav bar on a presented modal from the activity controller (such as Messages in your screen shot above) and never changes the color of the bar in the app itself.